# Differentiating between empty string indicating no value and indicating a blank value

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Django form that I am using to submit GET requests to.  The view takes the form input and uses it as arguments to filter a queryset to produce a list of search results.  I need to add blank and None choices to the top of the choices of one of the fields.  I want the blank value to mean "do not filter this field".  I want the None value to mean "filter this field for the state of being blank".  The problem I'm having is that in the method of my form that does the filtering, I need to check that the value is truthy (so that a blank submission does no filtering) and I need to convert the string 'None' explicitly to ''.

How do I write this code to differentiate between chooing a value that should not be filtered on and explicitly querying for ''?

```
class MyFilterForm(forms.Form):
    is_open = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('A', 'A'),
        ('B', 'B'),
        ('C', 'C'),
    )
    status = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=(('', 'All'),
                 ('None', 'None')) + STATUS_CHOICES,
        required=False)

    def filter_qs(self, qs):
        for key, value in self.cleaned_data.items():
            # Check for truthiness so that '' means do not filter
            if value:

                # Special treatment of 'None'
                # Convert 'None' to ''
                if value == 'None':
                    value = ''

                qs = qs.filter(**{key: value})
        return qs
```

Comment: Could you point to where your code fails the condition that you want?

Comment: It doesn't fail.  I'm looking for a cleaner way to implement passing form inputs to a queryset that does not involve special if statements.

Answer (score 0):

None is Falsey in Python, as is an empty string. To differentiate the two, use the is operator like so:

```
if value is None:
    #im none, do something
```

Your logic is very confusing - you want the empty string to mean dont filter, but the None value you change to blank, and want it to mean'the state of being blank', whatever that means...

the if value operator will only operate on non-empty strings and not None values, so your None logic in there will never be reached. So you could have (if I understand the logic);

```
if value:
    #do filtering
elif value is None:
    #do something with your None object
```

UPDATE:

filter on your qs like so:

```
new_qs = qs.filter(key=value if value != 'None' else '')
```

You dont need to unpack a dictionary with a single key as you are doing.

Comment: 2 points: 1) 'the state of being blank' means that the value of the field is empty string i.e. myobject.myfield == ''.  2) The None logic **is reached** because the value for the submitted choice of 'None' is 'None' which is a string, not the None value.  Refer to the choices keyword argument of the status field: ('None', 'None').

Comment: My question is not regarding the specifics of Python syntax.  What I'm asking is what is a clear way of processing the input a user submits through a select input so that the correct queryset is created.  Specifically this means that if the user selects 'All', the queryset should not be filtered; if the user selects 'None', the queryset should be filtered for the empty string.